# How to override Material-U FormHelperText component type?

Tags: material-ui

https://material-ui.com/api/form-helper-text/#props

it is not clear from this documentation

```
component | elementType | 'p' | The component used for the root node. Either a string to use a HTML element or a component.
```

Of how to properly override  - ie. use a 'div' instead of a 'p'

Comment: just pass a prop `component="div"`.

Comment: where? there is not a way to do that directly in the field props.

Answer (score 1):

You can set it in the `FormHelperTextProps` of `TextField` like so

```js
<TextField
  FormHelperTextProps={{ component: 'div' }}
  helperText="Your helper text"
/>
```

Note, that if you are using TypeScript that this is currently not correctly typed (see the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/33339)).

You then have to annotate the line with `// @ts-expect-error` or simply cast the props to `any`.

Answer (score -1):

```
  import {  makeStyles} from "material-ui/core"      
    
    const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
               
              field: {
               
                     "& .MuiFormHelperText-root": {
                           position: 'absolute',
                           bottom: -20
                        }
                                         
                   },
            })
        
        const Form =(props)=>{
          const classes = useStyles();
        return(  <TextField
                        variant="outlined"
                        margin="dense"
                        required
                        className={classes.field}
                        fullWidth
                        id="lastName"
                        label="Last Name"
               helperText={"This is sample error"}
                        name="lastName"
                        autoComplete="lname"
                        error
                        
                      />)
         }
```

**I think this is what you are looking for ...**

Comment: No, you are customizing styles, not the component type.